# Assets from data of objects

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I'm using nuxt.js and vue.js. But have an issue with adding images from data array of objects like this:

```
<img v-bind:src="~assets/img/image-name.jpg">
```

When I'm using /static it works fine.

```
<img v-bind:src="/img/image-name.jpg">
```

How can I use **~assets** with data from objects? Can you please help me with this?

**UPD**

Here is more details. I'm using data like this part:

```
products: [ { id: 1, imgSrc: 'img/product-img-1.jpg', } ]
```

Then in *.vue I'm using

```
<img v-bind:src="product.imgSrc">
```

(v-for is added in code too in block above img tag). It's works fine, because images are in /static/ folder.
But how can I use images from /assets folder for binding data from object? I thought something like this one:

`products: [ { id: 1, imgSrc: '~assets/img/product-img-1.jpg', } ]`

but it's not.

Comment: The v-bind directive is used to bind an attribute to a piece of data in your components `data` section.  Can you please show the Vue instance all of the is bound to?

Comment: thanks. I've updated my question

Comment: From looking at the nuxt.js documentation (https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets), the "~assets/..." format is used by the webpack loaders and translates to a static path when built for production systems.  It doesn't look like it's something you use at run-time.  But I'm not sure.  Might want to check with the nuxt.js folks.

Comment: After two year, you found some solution?